# Get Youtube video data with API v3 JSON to PHP variables

Tags: php, json, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to migrate from the old API and I'm struggling to understand the new API v3.  Basically I'm trying to make a PHP function that gets the video title, description, and statistics from the videoID.

I understand this will return the data I need but how do I convert it into PHP variables?

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='videoID'&key='APIKEY'&fields=items(id,snippet(title,description),statistics)&part=snippet,statistics
```

Comment: have you tried looking at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php

Comment: Yes I have tried looking at the PHP samples but I'm not trying to upload or manage videos via web form as shown in the samples. I just need the most simple method to retrieve the video data, convert it to php variables, and then display it

Comment: Well after 3 days of messing around with it I finally figured it out on my own.

Comment: And how did you do it?